# Cors doesnt solve cross origin requests

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webserver

I have trying to build an angular app using ASP.NET MVC Web API.

When i make a $resource request to my web server (localhost) I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:59636/api/studios. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:44060' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I read that installing Cors would solve this. But it doesnt. I have tried both enabling cors

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

as well as using an the attribute

```
[EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")]
```

It is working on IE

[image: maybe this helps? I am calling the default api/values]

Answer (score 0):

In your  WebApiConfig.cs file you should have:

```
        config.EnableCors();
```

In your ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs, in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials():

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                new[] { "http://localhost:44060" });
```

And over the controller:

```
[EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:44060", "*", "*")]
```

Comment: still not working. I have commented out

 `//config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
 //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));`
and removed authorized attribute from the controller